# dc.js bar chart with ordinal axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am making a simple bar chart getting a sum of revenue over the year. Below is the snippet of constructing the bar chart using dc.js

```
//INITIALIZE CROSSFILTER AND RELATED DIMENSIONS/AGGREGATES
var data = crossfilter([
    {revenue: 1487946,year: 2016}, 
    {revenue: 2612,year: 2016},
    {revenue: 2908,year: 2015},
    {revenue: 1648171,year: 2015 }]);

var dimension = data.dimension(function(d) {return d.year;});
var group = dimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.revenue;});

// MAKE A DC BAR CHART
dc.barChart("#bar-chart")
  .dimension(dimension)
  .group(group)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(dimension)) // Need the empty val to offset the first value
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal) // Tell Dc.js that we're using an ordinal x axis
  .brushOn(false)
  .centerBar(false)
  .gap(70);

console.log(dc.version);
dc.renderAll();
```

Its has to be noted that year is rendered as ordinal for simplicity.

With dc.js version - 1.7.5, The output was not clear :

[image: Untidy bar chart using dc.js 1.7.5].

With dc.js version - 2.x(beta) the output was much better:

[image]

Its not possible to use dc.js 2.x currently due to other conflicts. Any thoughts on making the bar chart better using dc.js 1.7.5?

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/say2sabarish/std1ugad/10/) to play around! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Added comments in the scriplet below:

```
dc.barChart("#bar-chart")
  .width(300) //give it a width
  .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 100})//give it margin left of 100 so that the y axis ticks dont cut off
  .dimension(dimension)
  .group(group)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(dimension)) // Need the empty val to offset the first value
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal) // Tell Dc.js that we're using an ordinal x axis
  .brushOn(false)
  .centerBar(false)
  .gap(7);//give it a gap of 7 instead of 70
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/hq2yamo9/)

Comment: Thanks! I got that too.. But doesn't the X-axis get a little offset in this? Is there anyway we can fix it?

Comment: I think that's the basic behavior of `xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)`

Comment: But aren't we seeing a glitch here? It should not offset. It didn't offset when I tried with dc.js  2.x. You might try too! 

That is why, i am hoping for some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary answer : **Avoid ordinal axes**

It could be a possible glitch with using dc.js 1.7.5. As for now, I was able to render the graphs by treating **the year as linear scale and treating ticks appropriately.**

Lets have this question open in case some one finds a better answer!